# Getting frequency of a signal from its phase

Tags: encoder, time, frequency-measurement, phase

How Can I get the real time frequency of a signal from its encoder phase angle. The encoder gives us a triangular wave from (0-2*pi). If I use derivation, I get discontinuity which provoke spikes.

Thank you.

Comment: You have to compute the derivative over a span which does not include discontinuities. I assume each encoder value has a time associated with it, right?

Comment: Wait - if I'm understanding this right, you just want to find the frequency of a sawtooth wave?

Answer (score 1):

You need to count how much the phase advances in a certain time period. As for the discontinuities, just add 2*pi each time you get a jump down.

Answer (score 0):

I agree. Frequency is in the time domain. You have to consider the sample rate or the period in real terms. There are two times during each cycle during which the derivative (slope) will be zero. They are the negative peak and the positive peak. You can capture the interval between the two. That is half the period which is 1/(twice the frequency).

I might be wasting your time. I just don't know what you have other than the PLL to play with.

Comment: This answer is quite misleading. Frequency is most certainly *not* in the time domain - it's the Fourier transform of the time domain. But see my answer.

Comment: Who said anything about a PLL?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your signal is more or less periodic, but the period may drift slowly over time. Defining an "instantaneous frequency" is sensible in this case. You can measure the average period \$T\$ over a long sampling time \$\tau\$. Then the "frequency" is equal to \$1/T\$ during that sampling time. I'm using quotes around the word "frequency" because really, the frequency domain is only straightforwardly defined over an infinite time span.

So what you really need to do is to measure the period. Normally you don't try to measure the period by taking the derivative, for the reasons you already found out.

In hardware, the standard approach is to use a comparator + counter to count the number of zero crossings in a given time interval. The signal needs to be AC coupled to the comparator with a high-pass corner frequency that is much lower than the signal frequency. The comparator also needs to have appropriate input hysteresis to avoid noise-induced bouncing. If you power the comparator from \$\pm 5\$ V, you can generate one TTL pulse per period, which can be counted by the digital counter.

Over a sampling time \$\tau\$ you will accumulate \$N\$ counts on the counter. The "frequency" is then equal to \$N/\tau\$. Note that you will need some kind of external clock to tell you the duration of your sampling time \$\tau\$! After each \$\tau\$, of course, you need to reset the counter.

In software, it's all quite a bit simpler - just mimic the hardware description above. You still need to know the clock speed of your ADC to find \$\tau\$ though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And if I use a PLL?

Comment: @downvoter, what do you think is the problem with my explanation?

Comment: @Ahmed Abrous: I don't see how you can use a PLL as a frequency counter. A PLL can be used to generate a new signal with a frequency that is related to your input frequency. But you would still have to count the frequency of the new signal. So how could using a PLL help?

Comment: What I would like to get is to know the frequency of my periodic signal, this is why I have thought to PLL. I have the position of my signal $(w*t+\phi)$ and I would like to get the w value.

Comment: If you already have your signal in terms of \$ \sin (\omega t + \phi) \$, then your original question is meaningless - you already know the frequency \$ \omega \$. If you just have a signal \$ S(t) \$ that looks roughly periodic, you need to do more work to extract \$ \omega \$.

Comment: PS. If you don't feel my answer is good enough to upvote or accept, why are you still asking me questions?

Comment: I explain the problem. I have a signal which is the phase angle of a signal given by an encoder (position of an encoder). I search the frequency of this periodic signal, but when I use a derivator I get discontinuities when the phase angle passes from +pi to -pi.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a peak detector:

[image]

and here's what it does:

[image]

As you can see, it outputs high-going pulses which occur precisely pi radians apart.

The time between pulses, then, corresponds to half the period (twice the frequency) of the sawtooth, so all that's necessary to do to determine the frequency of the sawtooth is to determine that time, multiply it by two to get the entire period, and take its reciprocal. Or, measure the time between every other pulse ( which is the same as dividing by two) and take its reciprocal. The latter method would be more accurate than the former because it would ignore the hysteresis between successive pulses.